# traj step1measures: why am I getting an NA error if I have no missing values?

Tags: r, na

This is what happens when I run traj::step1measures

`step1measures(datamat, timemat, ID = TRUE)`

> Error in if (cor.mat[i_row, i_col] > 0.999) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
> > 2.
> >     check.correlation(output[, -1], verbose)
> >
> > 1.
> >     step1measures(datamat, timemat, ID = TRUE)

I have checked multiple times and I am sure that there are no null or missing values in the data and time matrices. Any suggestions for what's going wrong here/ where a missing value could be popping up?

Comment: you checked datamat and timemat, but did you check cor.mat? In rstudio, you can explore the code of a function by selecting the function name in the console and typing F2

Comment: Thanks! I just tried to run a separate correlation of the two matrices (without the ID columns) and found the following: 
Both 'cor.test(datamat,timemat)'  and 'cor(c(datamat),c(timemat))' yield normal results. However, 'cor(datamat, timemat)' yields a seres of NAs and a warning that "the standard deviation is zero". I'm not sure if that's what's being used by traj::step1measures or why it wouldn't work if the other correlation test do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why you may be hitting this error:

1. At least one row of your data does not have the required number of
   data points. A minimum of 4 data points per row is required. You can
   see the data requirements in the function's documentation:
   https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/traj/traj.pdf
2. Your data contains an ID row but you did not indicate that to the function.
3. Any other unexpected data value combinations that yields 'Inf', 'NA' or 'NaN' for one of the measures. This is the sneaky one. You may need to go to line 416 of the step1measures script and view the data before it's passed to the correlation function. You may notice that some data rows contain the invalid values. I would recommend removing those rows. In an ideal world, the package would be able to catch such issues and display a better error but it's not the case today.

Comment: I had the same problem and noticed that it happens when there are some rows that consist only of zeros. I temporarily fixed it by adding 0.01 to all the values of the dataset.